# Convergence of the power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

Does the power series $\sum_{n=1}(1 - 1/sqrt(n))^n $ converge or diverge?

I tried root test but it doesn't work. Which convergence test should I try to solve the problem?

Comment: consider the function $f(x) = (1-x)^{1/x^2}$ when $x \to 0^{+}$. compute the limit, if it is $0$, the limit of the derivative, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline: After a while, $\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$ will be close to $e^{-1}$, and in particular will be positive and less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Thus after a while $\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n}$ is positive and less than $\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$.

To finish, show that after a while $2^{\sqrt{n}}\gt n^2$. From this we can conclude that our series converges.

Comment: Sorry. I don't see why (1-1/sqrt(n))^sqrt(n) is close to e^-1. Can you illustrate more on this part?

Comment: It is a standard limit fact that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{m}\right)^m=e^x$. We take $x=-1$.

Comment: You are welcome. If you wish to use another style of doing basically the same thing, note that our $n$-th term is $\exp(n\ln(1-1/\sqrt{n})$. Now use the estimate $-1/\sqrt{n}$ for the logarithm part. (This comes from the power series for $\ln(1+x)$).

Comment: But i get $exp(nln(1-1/sqrt(n)) > e^(-sqrt(n)) $ from this method. How could it be smaller than 1/2^sqrt(n) then?

Comment: Oh. Nevermind. I think I made a mistake. It should be smaller than. Thanks for helping!

Comment: We get, *approximately*, that the exp is about $e^{-\sqrt{n}}$, that is, $\frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{n}}}$. Since $e\gt 2$, this is less than $\frac{1}{2^{\sqrt{n}}}$.

Comment: The more formal version is that $n\ln(1-1/\sqrt{n})=-\sqrt{n}+O(1)$, since the next term in the series expansion of $\ln(1-1/\sqrt{n})$ is a constant divided by $n$.